# Calculus- limits , continuity, min/max

Tags: calculus

Let  $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ be continuous and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=2  $ and $f(0)=1$.

A) Prove $f$ is bounded.

B) Prove $f(x)$ has a minimum in $[0,\infty)$.

C) Give an example of such function that does not have a maximum in $[0,\infty)$.

I know how to prove A and B. As for C, I thought of the function $f(x) = \frac{2x^2 +1 }{x^2 +1} $. But I really want to find such a function that won't be defined on $(-\infty,0)$. Is there any such example? Maybe something like $\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} $  but less artificial?

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want one that won't be defined on $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: Also, please give the question a more specific title. You have a lot of room up there to say something about what you're asking.

Comment: I think you have to be a little more specific. What do you mean by "less artificial"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C, how about something which approaches 2 at $\infty$, here is an ugly example:

$f(x) = \max(1,\sqrt{2-1/x} )$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: Looks good to me ! (although it is defined anywhere :) )

Comment: @homogenity I didnt read your post completely. I don't know what you mean by 'you only want it to be defined on $[0,\infty)$'. I could have just written my function for $x \geq 0$, then it is a function defined on $[0,\infty)$. Sure we can extend this function to $\mathbb{R}$, but it is still a valid, like the answer you gave in the question.